# Create select option with looping javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a select option with HTML and PHP using for loop.

Here's the code

```
 <select id="room" class="form-control" name="room">
 <?php
     for( $i=1; $i<=10; $i++ )
     {
         echo '<option value="'.$i.'"> Room '.$i.'</option>';
     }
  ?>
  </select>
```

I want to ask how I create it with javascript ? I need because the limit like `$i<=10` in the code above for option I created, I get it from API response.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the same way as you did on php, but you have to create and append the option elements instead of `echo`ing.

```js
const TOTAL_OPTIONS = 10;
const select = document.getElementById("room");

for (let i = 1; i <= TOTAL_OPTIONS; i++) {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
  option.innerHTML = `Room ${i}`;

  select.appendChild(option);
}

select.addEventListener("change", (e) => console.log(e.target.value));
```

```html
<select id="room" class="form-control" name="room"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HTML text, string interpolation and `.insertAdjacentHTML()`.

```js
const qty = 10;
const room = document.querySelector("#room");

for (let i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
  room.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value="${i}">Room ${i}</option>`);
}
```

```html
<select id="room" class="form-control" name="room"></select>
```